# Hiding a popup in a webview

Tags: ios, uiview, xamarin.ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I am new to iOS programming (Xamarin). I want to show a view when a link in a popup in a webview is clicked. (image attached)[Popup picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqJMF.png)

```
if(msg == "Settings")
            {
                UIStoryboard storyBoard = UIStoryboard.FromName("MobileSettings", null);
                MobileSettingsViewController mobileView = storyBoard.InstantiateViewController("MobileSettingsViewController") as MobileSettingsViewController;

                PresentViewController(mobileView, false, null);

            }
```

When I am done with this view I remove this view like the below code in that view's controller class.

```
cancelButton.TouchUpInside += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                this.DismissViewController(false, null);
            };
```

Now the problem is, the popup is still showing in the webview and I am not sure how to hide it.
[Popup picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqJMF.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Is the PresentViewController and DismissViewController in the same `UIViewController`, can you show more code refer to [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? 2. Can you try to override `TouchesBegan`  like ` public override void TouchesBegan(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
        {
            base.TouchesBegan(touches, evt);
            this.DismissViewController(false, null);
        }`

Comment: 3. Add a breakpoint at `cancelButton.TouchUpInside` to see if it can get there when clicking the button.

Comment: The PresentViewController is in the view controller of the webview and the DismissViewController is in the second ViewController. It looks like the popup will be closed from the webview. Thank you!